# Why Android TextView addTextChangedListener causes setEllipsize and setMaxLines to be invalid?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, android-source

When I use the "**addTextChangedListener**" api to the **Android TextView**, the original effect of "**setEllipsize**" and "**setMaxLines**" in multi-line will be invalid.

Why? And does anyone know how to solve it?  I want them to be compatible with each other

I have tried various ways to call them, but it still doesn’t work.

This is my simple activity code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "TestActivity";
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    tv = findViewById(R.id.tv_test);
    tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
    tv.setMaxLines(3);
    tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            Log.i(TAG,"beforeTextChanged s:" + s.toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Log.i(TAG,"onTextChanged s:" + s.toString());
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Log.i(TAG,"afterTextChanged s:"+s.toString());
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String text = "The annual Apple new product launch conference is here again. Although the basic information was revealed before the launch event as in previous years";
    tv.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

}

This is my simple layout xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my build.gradle(app) code:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.4.21'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.emojicompat"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Support Libraries
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji-appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji-bundled:1.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

    // Test
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.1"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The following is the effect picture currently affected
[Here is the Img link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR7AP.jpg)

In my imagination, it should appear with an ellipsis after the last word in the third line，but now there is nothing happen.

Thanks to everyone who lends a helping hand

Comment: anybody konws? I think that should be an easy problem to reproduce